# Dynamically add attributes to instance and use attribute like @Property with get and set

Tags: python

Im learning Python here so please spare me for silly questions. I Encounter an issue with adding attribute to a class instance

I have a dictionary of people with name,age and strength, i.e

```
{
"Mary": {"age":25, "strength": 80},
"John": {"age": 40, "strength": 70},
...
}
```

and a class that will get in list of people as constructor input and add them as its own attribute, and when that attribute is called, it will return the age

i.e:

```
group = Person({dictionary of person})

# call person name as attribute, get back age

first_person = group.Mary  # return 25 here
group.John # return 40 here
```

However, each attribute will also need to maintain its behavior as a dict/object

```
group.Mary["strength"] # return 80 here
```

I tried `__get()__` but it seems to work only on class variables which is not this case since I need to create multiple group instances of class Person and they don't share variables.

Also tried `setattr()` but it will keep each attribute as a dict and therefore cannot directly call like `group.Mary`to get age

May I know is there any way in Python to implement this requirement?

Comment: try to subclass `dict` and override some methods to achieve the result

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. The expression `group.Mary["strength"]` essentially consists of 2 steps:

1. retrieving the attribute named `"Mary"` from the object `group`, and;
2. calling the method `__getitem__` on the retrieved attribute with argument `"strength"`.

However, note that in your example you require Step 1 (`group.Mary`) to return 25, which is an integer. Unfortunately, integers can't also be a mapping (objects that implement `__getitem__`).

Answer (score 0):

Added to class a method to create dynamically the properties but, for example, it can also be refactor as global function.

Each attribute is **private** and its access is ruled by the descriptors. Notice the **private** attributes created dynamically required a bit more of care, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71736689/16462878) for details and references.

```
class Person:
    @classmethod
    def property_factory(cls, name):
        # dynamical descriptors, -> private name mangling!
        p = property(fget=lambda self: getattr(self, f'_{cls.__name__}__{name}'), 
                     fset=lambda self, v: setattr(self, f'_{cls.__name__}__{name}', v))
        
        setattr(cls, name, p)

    def __init__(self, **p):
        # dynamically add properties
        for name in p.keys():
            self.property_factory(name)

        # initialization descriptors
        for name, d in p.items():
            setattr(self, name, d)


data = {"Mary": {"age":25, "strength": 80}, "John": {"age": 40, "strength": 70}}

p = Person(**data)

# check property
print(type(p).Mary)
#<property object at 0x7f5e5d469e00>
print(type(p.Mary))
#<class 'dict'>

# descriptors in action
p.Mary['age'] += 666
p.John['strength'] -= 666
print(p.John)
#{'age': 40, 'strength': -596}
print(p.Mary)
#{'age': 691, 'strength': 80}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, OP wants `p.Mary` to (a) return the age, i.e. 40, and not a dict, while also (b) behave like a dict supporting `__getitem__`. Your answer does (b) but not (a).

Comment: @kmkurn yes, **a posteriori** I also noticed it. The problem is that the question is bad posed, see the title and __"I Encounter an issue with adding attribute to a class instance"__ and the vague __"Also tried ..."__ Further,  there is no trace of any attempts which instead could be useful to get an idea of the encountered difficulties. For (a) see my comment to the question

Comment: hi, thanks for your replies, it seems not possible to achieve all desired behaviors at once so I must accept to find another way

Comment: @viet nguyen I think properties are not the right way. Have a look to [`enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) (notice that with python 3.11 this package was updated and there are new features such as `EnumType`)