# How do I call a specific function when a class variable changes?

Tags: python, class, attributes, decorator

I've created a class and initialized three variables a, b and c. Now I want to call a specific function `func1` whenever the variables a or c are changed from the outside, and a function `func2` when variable b is changed from the outside.

I am aware that this can be done using decorators, like this:

```
class Event:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self._a = a
        self._b = b
        self._c = c

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a
    @a.setter
    def a(self, value):
        self._a = value
        print("Variable a changed!")
        self.func1()

    @property
    def b(self):
        return self._b
    @b.setter
    def b(self, value):
        self._b = value
        print("Variable b changed!")
        self.func2()

    @property
    def c(self):
        return self._c
    @c.setter
    def c(self, value):
        self._c = value
        print("Variable c changed!")
        self.func1()

    def func1(self):
        print("Function 1 called")
    def func2(self):
        print("Function 2 called")

obj = Event(1, 2, 3)
obj.a = 15
obj.b = 10
obj.c = 5
```

My final code will have 8 or more variables however, and writing a designated @property and @var.setter for every single one of them will be very cumbersome and not really readable.

Is there a simpler way to just say `If variables a, c, f, ... are updated, call function X, if b, e, ... are updated, call function Y`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could subclass `property` with custom features. Here a *basic* example on how to do that. Notice you should provide a dictionary which maps which property triggers which function (as string).

```
class TriggerProperty(property):

    MAPPER = {'a': 'func1', 'b': 'func2', 'c': 'func1'}
    
    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        super().__set__(obj, value)
        func_name = self.MAPPER.get(self.fget.__name__)
        getattr(obj, func_name)()


class Event:
    # ...
    @TriggerProperty
    def a(self):
        return self._a

    @a.setter
    def a(self, value):
        self._a = value
        print("Variable a changed!")

    # ...
```

Comment: This works, but I still have to define `@TriggerProperty` and `@var.setter` for every variable, right? With many variables, this gets pretty confusing - is there any way to get around this?

Comment: That's part of the _descriptor protocol_. What you can do is to create the whole class or add only the property-methods dynamically, here an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71736689/16462878)

Comment: `TriggerProperty` itself can define the common behavior, so that all you need to write is `a = TriggerProprety()`, `b = TriggerProperty()`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a single property-like descriptor and use that to define each variable.

```py
class TriggerProperty:
    def __init__(self, callback):
        self.callback = callback

    def __set_name__(self, obj, name):
        self.private_name = "_" + name
        self.public_name = name

    def __get__(self, obj, obj_type):
        return getattr(obj, self.private_name)

    def __set__(self, obj, v):
        # Don't do this if the attribute is being created
        if hasattr(obj, self.private_name):
            self.callback()
            print(f'{self.public_name} changed!')

        return setattr(obj, self.private_name, v)

def func1():
    print("Function 1 called")

def func2():
    print("Function 2 called")

class Event:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    a = TriggerProperty(func1)
    b = TriggerProperty(func2)
    c = TriggerProperty(func1)
```

Then

```
>>> e = Event(1,2,3)
>>> e.a = 5
Function 1 called
a changed!
>>> e.b = 7
Function 2 called
b changed!
>>> e.c = 9
Function 1 called
c changed!
```

---

The [descriptor how-to](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) provides an example of how `property` might be defined in pure Python. You might want to study that to see if there is a way to define `TriggerProperty` as a subclass of `property`, instead of implementing the descriptor protocol explicitly as done above.

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for! Is it possible to move `func1` and `func2` into `class Event`?

Comment: The short answer is "yes". However, depending on how you are using them, keep the distinction between a function and a bound method in mind.

Comment: For example, as `func1` is just a function, inside `__set__` you'd have to say something like `self.callback(obj)` if `func1` expected access to the instance attributes of an instance of `Event`.

Comment: Hmmm okay. Basically, my usecase is the following: If the user updates any of the variables, I want to automatically recalculate everything (in `func1`or `func2`) that is affected by that change, without the neccessity for a specific work function that the user has to call manually after a parameter update.

Comment: So for example, if you had trapezoid, changing the length of any side could change the area or permiter, and changing the area or perimeter would scale each side by some fixed same amount?

Comment: Yes, that's a good example for what I want to do.

Comment: OK, then my previous comment applies. Because the `callback` attribute is a reference to a *function*, you have to say `self.callback(obj)`. One, `self` is the descriptor, not the `Event` instance, and two, `callback` is an instance attribute, not a class attribute, so `self.callback` doesn't turn into `TriggerProperty.callback(self, obj)`.